# Hibernate 5 - using NamedQuery not utilizing @FetchMode(SUBSELECT)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We are using the Hibernate `@NamedQuery` annotation on an Entity and are using join fetches to eagerly retrieve the data we want at query time. We have this working for the most part, but the `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` that we have on a relationship does not appear to be working. Instead, it appears that the query generated is still doing a single query with the join fetch, rather than the expected 2nd query.

Again, we're using Hibernate's `@NamedQuery` and not the JPA style.

The reason that we want to use the SUBSELECT for our case is that we have multiple `@OneToMany` relationships and we want to avoid massive perf issues with the Cartisean Product

Here's the setup we have:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(
                name = "StackOverflowNamedQuery",
                query = "SELECT distinct f FROM Foo f "
                        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH f.fooOneToMany bar " // This is a straight JOIN FETCH
                        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH bar.barOneToMany " //  WANT THIS TO DO A SUBSELECT
                        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH f.manyToOne_boo "
                        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH f.manyToOne_blah  "
                        + "WHERE f.id = :id "
                        + "f.isRemoved = false"
        )
)
```

Then over on Bar.getBarOneToMany(), here's the annotation setup we have for that OneToMany relationship

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
public Set<BarOneToMany> getBarOneToMany() {
        return barOneToMany;
}
```

So basically, we want to Fetch one of the OneToMany with a join fetch, and then we want the other one to be done by a SUBSELECT. Is this possible like this?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose `NamedQuery` means your taking over the SQL generation yourself so you would have to do two separate queries if you want two separate queries.

Comment: But this code will automatically "fetch" the f.fooOneToMany. My hope is that Hibernate knows how to use the @Fetch to figure out how to fetch it. If I wrote it with Criteriabuilder I think it works the way i want it to, but I want to use HQL to do the SUBSELECT