# OneToOne mapping not getting child entity while selecting parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

2 tables with OneToONe bidirectional mapping where column from parent table is unique not primary and column mapped in child table is primary.
Able to save the data in child table but when trying to parent entity getting 
Child entity is coming as null

Code for reference

Parent Entity:

```
@Column(name="REFERENCE_NO",unique = true)
private Long referenceNo;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parentObj", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ChildEntity childEntity ;
```

ChildEntity:

```
@Id
@Column(name="REFERENCE_NO")
Long referenceNo;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="REFERENCE_NO",referencedColumnName = "REFERENCE_NO")
private ParentEntity parentObj;
```

Comment: You have the childEntity null because you have set `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to the mapping, if you set the `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. I think you can remove the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` if isn't necessary.

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I tried removing "LAZY" same issue,  FetchType.EAGER does not work either .

Comment: @SternK I am using <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>

Comment: @RajanSharma if the propriety `childEntity` isn't loaded, the variable isn't inside the database, right? you can try to find it inside the database? if the variable doesn't is present, you should be assigned a value to `childEntity`, like `parentObj.setChild(childEntity);`

Answer (score 0):

You should change your fetch type.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

other option is to call a getter on parent when you want to reach your child object.

Comment: That is how I am trying to get 
if thats what you mean!
 Query query=this.getEm().createQuery("select s from ParentEntity s where s.referenceNo=:refNo");
  query.setParameter("refNo", refNo);
  return (ParentEntity )query.getSingleResult();

Comment: That's not a solid question. If you want to get child element on load, change fetch type. createQuery also looks quite obsolete to me, i`d prefer using @Query in Repository interface. Please provide an input, example and an expected output.

Comment: In above comments as mentioned I tried changing FetchType to eager did not work , originally query was a NamedQuery (@NamedQuery(name="ParentEntity.findAll", query="SELECT v FROM ParentEntity v"),) just trying out different things , also even if the query is obsolete that should not affect the output , so the basic question here is when the ParentEntity is loading why is child entity not loading is there something externally I need to specify to get child enity on load .

Comment: seems you have to manually join child in your query. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087466/hibernate-5-using-namedquery-not-utilizing-fetchmodesubselect)

Comment: Appreciate your input  but that's a workaround I was just wondering why its not happening internally , is it because when it's trying to select since the column of parent entity is not primary key its not able to associate the child entity with @OneToOne or something else 
I tried with the primary key it works but not with Unique key!